# App crashes when launching another activity

Tags: java, android

I searched everywhere for a solution to my problem, but couldn't get one.So, the problem is I want to launch another activity called `FifthActivity` from my `MainActivity` via the button but my activity keeps crashing. I checked the `logcat` and found this -

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.india.chemistry/com.example.india.chemistry.FifthActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Below is my mainActivity java file.

```
package com.example.india.chemistry;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static boolean isRunning = false;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(!isRunning)
        {
            isRunning = true;
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Intro.class));//Play your video here
        }
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void part_a( View View){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.Second_Activity");
            startActivity(intent1);
    }

    public void part_b( View View) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.ThirdActivity");
        startActivity(intent2);
    }

    public void formulas( View View) {
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(this,FifthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent4);
    }    
}
```

Below is my `FifthActivity.java` file.

```
package com.example.india.chemistry;


public class FifthActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {
    final Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.shake);
    final Animation bounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.bounce);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fifth);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fifth, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();    

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


        public void nernst(View View) {
            Intent intentf1 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.nernst_activity");
            startActivity(intentf1);
        }

        public void waterhardness(View View) {
            Intent intentf2 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.WaterHardness");
            startActivity(intentf2);

        }

        public void determinationOfCao(View view) {
            Intent intentf3 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.CementCao");
            startActivity(intentf3);
        }

        public void COD_waste_water(View view) {
            Intent intentf4 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.COD");
            startActivity(intentf4);
        }

        public void C_in_B(View view) {
            Intent intentf5 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.Copper_in_Brass");
            startActivity(intentf5);
        }

        public void alkalinity(View view) {
            Intent intentf6 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.Alkalinity");
            startActivity(intentf6);
        }

        public void haematite_ore(View view) {
            Intent intentf7 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.HaemetiteOre");
            startActivity(intentf7);
        }

        public void colourimetry_copper(View view) {
            Intent intentf8 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.Colourimetric_Copper");
            startActivity(intentf8);
        }

        public void potentiometry_fas(View view) {
            Intent intentf9 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.Potentiometry_fas");
            startActivity(intentf9);
        }

        public void conductometry(View view) {
            Intent intentf10 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.Conductometry");
            startActivity(intentf10);
        }

        public void pka(View view) {
            Intent intentf11 = new Intent("com.example.india.chemistry.pka");
            startActivity(intentf11);
        }



}
```

Below is the logcat.

```
10-14 17:13:58.145 15430-15430/com.example.india.chemistry E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.india.chemistry, PID: 15430 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.india.chemistry/com.example.india.chemistry.FifthActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
at com.example.india.chemistry.FifthActivity.<init>(FifthActivity.java:21)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1085)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if problem solved or not.....

```
Animation shake,bounce;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fifth);

    shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.shake);
    bounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.bounce);

}
```

Comment: yes. Because you can use getApplicationContext() only after activity created. you can not use activity context before activity onCreate

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `getApplicationContext`(result in null) before `oncreate` because activity has not been created properly yet so you need to call this once your `oncreate` has been executed or after the `super` call .

The super call of `onCreate` fetches the application context for your activity.

Solution :

So either put your code inside `oncreate` or create a function and call it from inside `oncreate` after the `super` call.

Note : you will have to avoid `final` to make your `identifiers` global because the lazy initialization with `final` only works with `constructors` but don't worry , `onCreate` gets executed once when your activity is created or recreated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the activity in your manifest file, under application. Whenever you create a new activity add it to manifest file.

```
<application
...
<activity
            android:name=". FifthActivity"
            android:label="Fifth" />
...
</application>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class FifthActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {
    Animation shake,bounce;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fifth);
shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.shake);
    bounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.bounce);
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation also

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked! Although i did not understand why the problem occured and how it was fixed by those codes.

Comment: @ChinmayaKN approve if it was helpful

Comment: @Vyacheslav Thank you!

Comment: @ChinmayaKN , the problem is about `context` of the application. The best solution is to initialize the variables which are used context inside `oncreate` method .

Answer (score 0):

Your view has not yet been created, move :

```
shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.shake);
bounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.bounce);
```

To your oncreate method.

Answer (score 0):

**stack trace**'s first line gives Detailed information  : getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference.Means Activity was not created,it's return null Context. You make a both animation's Object Globally. try to edit your code this way.

```
public class FifthActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {

Animation shake,bounce; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fifth);

    shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
        R.anim.shake);
    bounce = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.bounce);
}
```

}